# Add text before array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm currently working on a data visualisation with d3.js where I have GDP data data for each quarter of a year. The data looks like this:

```js
[
    [
      "1947-01-01",
      243.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-04-01",
      246.3
    ],
    [
      "1947-07-01",
      250.1
    ]
 ]
```

What I want is turn it into the following:

```js
[
    [
      date: "1947-01-01",
      GDP: 243.1
    ],
    [
      date: "1947-04-01",
      GDP: 246.3
    ],
    [
      date: "1947-07-01",
      GDP: 250.1
]
```

I tried doing it like this but it turns the array elements into strings.

```js
d3.json("data/GDP-data.json").then(function (dataTotal) {
    data = dataTotal.data;
    console.log(data);

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        data[i]["0"] = new Date(data[i]["0"])
        data[i]["0"]="date: "+data[i]["0"];
        
        data[i][1] = "GDP: "+data[i][1];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to not turn each element into a string while still adding text before it? It would make it a lot easier to call certain data points.

Comment: Your output format is invalid, check the answer to see if you are looking for an array of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`

```
arr.map( s => ({ date : s[0], gdp : s[1] }) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [
  [
    "1947-01-01",
    243.1
  ],
  [
    "1947-04-01",
    246.3
  ],
  [
    "1947-07-01",
    250.1
  ]
];
var output = arr.map(s => ({
  date: s[0],
  gdp: s[1]
}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to achieve that

```js
var data = [
    [
      "1947-01-01",
      243.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-04-01",
      246.3
    ],
    [
      "1947-07-01",
      250.1
    ]
 ];
 
 var r = data.map(o=> ({date: o[0], GDP: o[1]}));
 
 console.log(r)
```